# What is the font of these control labels?

Tags: manipulate, fonts, gui-construction

What is the font of these control labels? I've gone through every font Mathematica offers (through the format GUI) and don't see a match. Haven't had any luck with default format files either. I'm trying to add notes under the controls and can't get a matching font (the notes below are close, but not identical). I could change all the fonts, yes, but I like this one.

[image: Manipulate Controls]

Answer (score 11):

```
CurrentValue["ControlsFontFamily"]
(* "Segoe UI"  on Version 9 / Windows 8 *)
(* "Lucida Grande" on OS X 10.6.8 -- thanks: m_goldberg *)
(* "Bitstream Vera Sans" on Fedora 20 -- thanks Oska *)
CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"]
(* 12 on Version 9 / Windows 8 *)

Style[StringJoin[CharacterRange["a", "z"]],
 FontFamily :> CurrentValue["ControlsFontFamily"],
 FontSize :> CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"]]
```

[image]

Update: On Version 9 Windows 8, `"PanelFontFamily"` gives the same result:

```
CurrentValue["PanelFontFamily"]
(* "Segoe UI" *)
CurrentValue["PanelFontSize"]
(* 12 *)
```

So do  the combinations `"MenuFontFamily"`  and `"MenuFontSize"`, and  `"TooltipFontFamily"` and `"TooltipFontSize"`. (* thanks: @Mike Honeychurch *)

Comment: This gives "Lucida Grande" on OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Note that there is also "MenuFontFamily", "MenuFontSize", "TooltipFontFamily", "TooltipFontSize".

Comment: thank you @Mike; I added those combinations.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like "Lucida Sans Unicode" on Windows or "Lucida Grande" on OSX. But it's hard to be sure. It'll render differently on Windows and OSX (and AFAIK also differently on older versions of Windows). I'm guessing your screenshot is from Windows, since the kerning is closer to that used by "Lucida Sans Unicode".