# What's the name of the default font used in Mathematica 10?

Tags: front-end, fonts

I really like the default font in *Mathematica* 10. So I would like to use it for my other applications. I tried to search for the name of the font, only found that a lot of people is talking on how to change it to another font.

Anybody knows what's the name of this default font?

Comment: ``System`$DefaultFont`` gives `{Courier,10.}`; is this what you need?

Comment: related Q/A: [What is the font of these control labels?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61502/125)

Comment: @kguler Yes! This font looks great in Mathematica, but not so well in other applications. (Maybe it's subjective to my opinion.) Good to know the `System` command. Thank you!

Comment: actually you don't need to use the context name for the ``System``` context, `$DefaultFont` is suficient.

Comment: @kguler Yes, it works. There're a lot to learn for me. To quote Sal Mangono, Mathematica is the software to have if one is stranded on a desert island with only a laptop (and presumably a large solar panel).

Comment: I don't think you can trust [`$DefaultFont`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$DefaultFont.html); it's been obsolete for a long time.

Comment: @m_goldberg Then what's the recommended method?

Comment: On OS X I find the font by putting the cursor into a cell and pressing Cmnd + T.

Comment: @m_goldberg I can't figure out what's the related keys on Windows. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Try choosing Show Fonts... from the Format menu. (The menu also shows the shortcut on OS X)

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes, I can see the font in this way. The menu is "Font...", and no shortcut. I can view font, but cannot change font here. I guess the menu name "Show Fonts..." on OS X make more sense.

Comment: @m_goldberg doesn't seem correct: on my Linux Mathematica 10 the font chosen in the dialog is _Bitstream Vera Sans_, while actual cell font is clearly serif. By some comparison of cell font with the fonts in the list I've come to a conclusion that on Linux it's really _Courier_. Similar is _FreeMono_, but it doesn't look quite the same.