# Letter g rendered with different descender styles

Tags: syntax, fonts, windows

I've just noticed that *Mathematica* renders `g` in two distinct ways: either with a closed descender or a open descender. Seems it happens only for local variables.

- g with open descender:
  [image: Single-story g]
- g with closed descender:
  [image]

Does anyone know what/why this is happening?

---

**Edit** : An example for *Manuel --Moe-- G*:

[image: example]

*Both* kinds of `g` are rendered.

- Mathematica 11.0.1.0 on Windows

Comment: I'm not sure I've used the correct tag…

Comment: could you please add a screenshot of the "double-story" `g` rendering of a local variable? have never seen this before on a local variable

Comment: Please post code blocks that produce both forms of `g`

Comment: It depends on the font. v10 and v11 use different fonts. Do you have a screenshot where you see both in the same notebook in cells of the same style?

Comment: Ok, I've just added an example.

Comment: The "single story" appears when the font is italic (pattern names). It looks like it isn't using the correct font for italics. Did you change the font? If yes, does your chosen font have an italic version installed?

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh you're right it just seems to be the italic g that is different. I haven't changed the fond yet…

Comment: By the way, I suppose italic means it 's a local variable of the function totV?

Comment: No, it means it's a pattern name or a function argument.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks!

Comment: I have confirmed that on Windows, *Mathematica* 11.0.1, renders `g` in two different ways depending on italic or regular.  Would you kindly check if `a` is also rendered in two different ways?

Comment: @QuantumDot You're right, there is the same behaviour for `a`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out what was happening.

[Mathematica 11 uses different fonts on Windows, OS X and Linux.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123736/12)  They are Consolas, Source Code Pro and Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, respectively.

Some fonts use different descender styles for the Italic and Roman versions.  Source Code Pro doesn't, so people on OS X cannot see this behaviour.  But Consolas does.

[image]

The difference you are seeing is simply the difference between the Italic and Roman versions of the same font.

Mathematica uses Italics for pattern names and function arguments.

What you see is entirely normal and there is no problem with either your Mathematica installation or the fonts installed on your system.  If it bothers you, you can change the default code font [like this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123922/12).

Comment: (+1) I would add that it is possible to [change the default font](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123850/280) and get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer. It is a comment that includes an image.

I am running V11.0.1 on OS X. I do not see the problem the OP is having. Suggest that it OS dependent and the question be tagged as Windows specific.

[image: code]